# Shell script - move files into folder

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose a particular command generates few files (I dont know the name of these files). I want to move those files into a new folder. How to do it in shell script?

i can't use :

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir newfolder
command 
mv * newfolder
```

as the cwd contains lot of other files as well.

Comment: One elegant solution is to pass the output folder into the command, like so: `command newfolder` ... If you can't change the command, cd new folder, take it's dependencies into new folder; run command with it's correct inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first question is can you just run `command` with `newfolder` as the current directory to generate the files in the right place it begin with:

```
mkdir newfolder
cd newfolder
command
```

Or if `command` is not in the path:

```
mkdir newfolder
cd newfolder
../command
```

If you can't do this then you'll need to capture lists of before and after files and compare.  An inelegant way of doing this would be as follows:

```
# Make sure before.txt is in the before list so it isn't in the list of new files
touch before.txt

# Capture the files before the command
ls -1 > before.txt

# Run the command
command

# Capture the list of files after
ls -1 > after.txt

# Use diff to compare the lists, only printing new entries
NEWFILES=`diff --old-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format="" --new-line-format="%l " before.txt after.txt`

# Remove our temporary files
rm before.txt after.txt

# Move the files to the new folder
mkdir newfolder
mv $NEWFILES newfolder
```

Comment: Thanks Dave Webb, The way you have written the answer would certainly going to help me. I learned new things on raising this question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to move them into a sub-folder:

```
mv `find . -type f -maxdepth 1` newfolder
```

Setting a `-maxdepth 1` will only find the files in the current directory and will not recurse. Passing in `-type f` means "find all files" ("d" would, respectively, mean "find all directories").

Comment: Hi carlspring,Thanks for your feedback. can you please explain me above script. Actually i could not understand 'maxdepth'

Comment: If there are too many files in the folder, an error might occur, then you could try this version of `find`:
`find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec "mv {} newfolder \;"`

Answer (score 1):

use pattern matching:

```
  $ ls *.jpg         # List all JPEG files
  $ ls ?.jpg         # List JPEG files with 1 char names (eg a.jpg, 1.jpg)
  $ rm [A-Z]*.jpg    # Remove JPEG files that start with a capital letter
```

Example shamelessly taken from [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) where you can find some more useful information about it.

Comment: Hi, matcheek, I don't know anything about the output files. so pattern matching is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your command prints out names with one per line, this script will work.

```
my_command | xargs -I {} mv -t "$dest_dir" {}
```